# If else function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I need something like a if else function in my jquery but I don't know how I have to do that. Or isn't it possible?

```
 if  $(".image1").click(function(){

        $(idnumbers).css("display", "block");
        $(idnumberp).css("display", "none");
        $(idnumber).css("display","block");  
  });



 else if $(".image2").click(function(){
        $(idnumbers2).css("display", "block");
        $(idnumberp).css("display", "none");
        $(idnumber).css("display","block");  

  });



 else $(".image3").click(function(){

        $(idnumbers3).css("display", "block");
        $(idnumberp).css("display", "none");
        $(idnumber).css("display","block");  

   });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you not just want the 3 event handlers?

Comment: Those are event handlers; you don't need the `if` or `else` at all. They will only run when the element is clicked.

Comment: The .click function doesn't fire until someone clicks on that element so you shouldn't need the if else block.

Comment: [Please avoid linking to w3schools.com.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @dezso: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: Are you trying to write code as in "`if` an element with class `image1` is `click`ed, run this `function`"? If so, that's not what JavaScript's `if` is for. jQuery `.click` implies the "if" in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to put your event handlers in to if statements. By attaching the event to the element 'onClick' listener, you're already handling each specific case.

```
$(".image1").click(function(){
    $(idnumbers).css("display", "block");
    $(idnumberp).css("display", "none");
    $(idnumber).css("display","block");  
});

$(".image2").click(function(){
    $(idnumbers2).css("display", "block");
    $(idnumberp).css("display", "none");
    $(idnumber).css("display","block");  
});

$(".image3").click(function(){
    $(idnumbers3).css("display", "block");
    $(idnumberp).css("display", "none");
    $(idnumber).css("display","block");  
});
```

This should do what you need without the extraneous if/else statements.

Answer (score 2):

You really want something like this:

```
function imageClick()
{       
    $(idnumberp).css("display", "none");         
    $(idnumber).css("display","block");     
};

$(".image1").click(function(){ $(idnumbers).css("display", "block"); imageClick(); });
$(".image2").click(function(){ $(idnumbers2).css("display", "block"); imageClick(); });
$(".image3").click(function(){ $(idnumbers3).css("display", "block"); imageClick(); });
```